# Is CQL executable available anwhere online?

Tags: software, cql

[This article](https://www.chess.com/blog/Geiss/chess-query-language-cql) and some questions on this forum - mention http://www.rbnn.com/cql/ as a source for getting cql.exe, but that domain seems unclaimed at the moment. Is this executable available anywhere else online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it from [the archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160226050834/http://www.rbnn.com/cql/cql.zip). Also the former rbnn website is preserved [there](https://web.archive.org/web/20140130143815/http://www.rbnn.com/cql/).

Answer (score 2):

You can find it on the initial developer's (Gady Costeff) website: http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql.

You can download the Windows and Mac executables from [the download page](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/download.html). For the Linux version, you should email the author (see the [FAQ](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/faq.html) no. 5 for the email).